# Unable to insert a box around an image div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to insert an image in a box (middle one in the pic) as per the image below:
[image]

and I have the following code for it:

```
 <div id="img-div">
        <img src="/images/NelsonM.JPG" alt="Nelson">
        <figcaption>Nelson Mandela</figcaption>
    </div>
```

and my css is:

```js
    #img-div {
      text-align: center;
     
    }
```

The image does go to the center, but I am not able to put a box as per the picture above.
Any hints please

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just need to paint a box around the parent div with a border.

```
#img-div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: well, it does put a box around the pic, but has got to have the same width as the box above and below...

Comment: If I use the same div width as the top box, the all thing just shifts to the left...

Comment: Ah ok, if your image's parent element is full width then I suggest giving your image tag `margin: o auto;`

Answer (score -1):

It is answer!! Wow:

```js
element.style.display = 'grid'
element.style.alignContent = 'center
```

Comment: are you saying that I should add that code into my css? At this stage I am not using "grid" in my code, just "divs"